# MariaDB 10.0.36: Table './mysql/servers.MYI' is read only

Tags: mariadb

Trying to upgrade `MariaDB` using Generic Linux package from https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.0/#os_group=linux_generic on a `Debian 8` server:

- kernel version `2.6.32-49-pve`
- OpenVZ/Virtuozzo container

Have no issue with `MariaDB 10.0.35`. The SQL server starts, no issue found. Hence it can not be an issue with files/folders permissions. None of master/slave replication is enabled.

But `MariaDB 10.0.36` does not start due to the following errors:

```
180909 17:04:07 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
180909 17:04:07 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table './mysql/servers.MYI' is read only
180909 17:04:07 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
180909 17:04:07 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table './mysql/host.MYI' is read only
180909 17:04:07 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
```

That's weird, if I roll binaries back to `MariaDB 10.0.35` and starts fine again.

The server have `selinux` disabled, and `AppArmor` does not seem to be enabled.

```
root@hosting:/etc/apparmor.d# service apparmor status
● apparmor.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
root@hosting:/etc/apparmor.d#
```

A fresh installed `MariaDB 5.5.x` fails the same way even after:

```
/usr/local/mysql/scripts/mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local/mysql/
```

it installs all the tables and fails to start afterwards.

So we can't start any other MariaDB version, but 10.0.35.

What else can it be? What do I miss?

Regards,
Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `datadir=` in `/etc/my.cnf` from `/home/mysql/` and moved databases to `/var/lib/mysql/`:

```
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/
```

and `MariaDB 10.0.36` started fine.

But why? What do I miss?

Regards, 
Alex.